# Возможно ли сделать сокращенную запись для if в данном случае?

Tags: php, laravel

подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли сделать сокращенные записи для if?

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $categoryIds = $request->get('categories');
    $attributes = $request->get('attributes');

    if ($categoryIds) {
        $request->session()->flash('category', end($categoryIds));
    }

    if ($attributes) {
        $request->session()->flash('attributes', $attributes);
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'categories' => 'present|array',
        'attributes' => 'present|array',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('welcome');
    }

    return redirect()->route('welcome')->with('success', 'Создание прошло успешно');
}
```

Comment: По-моему нет смысла, попытки сократить здесь что-либо ухудшат читабельность кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, *есесна*, упороться и сделать вот так:

**CategoryRequest.php**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * The URI to redirect to if validation fails.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirect = '/';

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'categories' => 'present|array',
            'attributes' => 'present|array',
        ];
    }
}
```

**HasCategory.php**

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class HasCategory
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->get('categories')) {
            $request->session()->flash('category', end($request>get('categories')));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**HasAttribute.php**

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class HasAttribute
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->get('attributes')) {
            $request->session()->flash('attributes', end($request>get('attributes')));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**контроллер**

```
use Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline;

protected $store = [
    HasAttribute::class,
    HasCategory::class
];

public function create(CategoryRequest $request, Pipeline $pipeline)
{
    $pipeline->send($request)->through($this->store)->thenReturn();
}
```

Что сделано?

1. Выкинули валидацию в отдельную сущность
2. Опрокидываем флэш через пайпы

Пайпы толком не описаны в доке, но про Request можно почитать.

Нужно еще подправить вывод алертов и неймспейсики подставить, та и усе

Answer (score 0):

**Нет никакой** "сокращенной записи для if". Это заблуждение, по какой-то причине очень распространённое.

Есть [тернарный оператор](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), который реализует очень ограниченную функциональность, которую можно сформулировать как  **присвоение значения по результатам условия**.

Использовать его в данном коде можно, но не нужно - это ухудшит читабельность.

Comment: Во-первых, есть return, который ничем не хуже. Во-вторых, я привык, что сокращённой записью if называют не условный оператор, а операторы `&&` и `||`. По крайней мере в js.

Comment: В РНР "сокращённым if" называют тернарный оператор.

Comment: Применение тернарного оператора возможно в `return`.

Comment: дада я неправ. мой ответ некорректен и забить себе в ногу гвоздь задача технически реализуемая

Comment: Всего-то гвоздь, а на плюсах можно и пулю, и не только в ногу xD

Answer (score 0):

Ну, предположим, вот:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $categoryIds = $request->get('categories');
    $attributes = $request->get('attributes');

    $categoryIds && $request->session()->flash('category', end($categoryIds));
    $attributes && $request->session()->flash('attributes', $attributes);

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'categories' => 'present|array',
        'attributes' => 'present|array',
    ]);

    return $validator->fails()
        ? redirect()->route('welcome')
        : redirect()->route('welcome')->with('success', 'Создание прошло успешно');
}
```

Comment: Как написали в комментариях, польза такого переписывания весьма сомнительна и стремится к отрицательным величинам.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а я и не утверждал, что оно полезно. Тем не менее, оно возможно.

Comment: @Ипатьев, @Qwertiy конкретно тот участок кода относится к Laravel, и в нем идеологически правильно делать, как написал @k0mar. Сократили 1 if. Кажется, это не много. Но кроме `store` есть `update`, где мы еще раз сэкономим 1 if и избавимся от дублирования кода.

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну не знаю, я не любитель городить 4 класса ради кода, который помещается на полэкрана.

Comment: @Qwertiy, причина не в количестве экранов и количестве кода. Даже наоборот, рекомендуется создавать классы, чтобы использовать полиморфизм взамен if. В Laravel это вообще [хрестоматийно](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests), движок сам создает нужный объект под объявленный в методе тип. По данной ситуации - 1. В контроллер приходит уже валидированный запрос, и все, кто знаком с Laravel, знает как это работает и где искать. 2. Однозначно - DRY, так как проверки можно устраивать в разных местах, а тут явно для этого создается класс.